# PDFLib how to print name value pairs?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, pdflib

I'm using PDFLib (this library https://www.pdflib.com/). I'm on PHP but this library exists also for other languages, so the question is not specific for PHP.

I would like to print on the PDF name value pairs. Something like this:
[image: expected output]

I know the easiest solution would be to use a table, but I can't because the PDF has to be **accessible** and they told me that, on PDF, a table to show name-value paris would not be accessible, so **I have to find another solution instead of table**.

Currently I tried with Textflow:

```
<?php
$upperX = 525;
$upperY = 780;
$lowerX = 70;
$lowerY = 50;

$y = $upperY;
$x = 70;

$pdf = new \PDFlib();
$pdf->begin_document('', '');
$pdf->begin_page_ext(0, 0, 'width=a4.width height=a4.height');

// Write "Name-Value paris:"
$optlist = "fontname={Helvetica} fontsize=8 encoding=utf8 alignment=center fakebold=true";
$tf = 0;
$tf = $pdf->add_textflow($tf, "Name-Value paris:", $optlist);
$pdf->fit_textflow($tf, $x, $lowerY, $upperX, $y, '');
$pdf->delete_textflow($tf);

$y -= 10;

// Write the pairs
$label_optlist = "fontname={Helvetica} fontsize=7 encoding=utf8 fakebold=true leftindent=0%";
$value_optlist = "fontname={Helvetica} fontsize=7 encoding=utf8 fakebold=false leftindent=22%";

$tf = 0;
$tf = $pdf->add_textflow($tf, "Name:", $label_optlist);
$tf = $pdf->add_textflow($tf, "John", $value_optlist);
$pdf->fit_textflow($tf, $x, $lowerY, $upperX, $y, '');
$pdf->delete_textflow($tf);
$y = $pdf->get_option('texty', ''); // Get Y where the above textflow ends

$tf = 0;
$tf = $pdf->add_textflow($tf, "Surname:", $label_optlist);
$tf = $pdf->add_textflow($tf, "Doe", $value_optlist);
$pdf->fit_textflow($tf, $x, $lowerY, $upperX, $y, '');
$pdf->delete_textflow($tf);
$y = $pdf->get_option('texty', '');

$tf = 0;
$tf = $pdf->add_textflow($tf, "Date of birth:", $label_optlist);
$tf = $pdf->add_textflow($tf, "2022/11/08", $value_optlist);
$pdf->fit_textflow($tf, $x, $lowerY, $upperX, $y, '');
$pdf->delete_textflow($tf);
$y = $pdf->get_option('texty', '');

$tf = 0;
$tf = $pdf->add_textflow($tf, "A key that has a long value:", $label_optlist);
$tf = $pdf->add_textflow($tf, "A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long value", $value_optlist);
$pdf->fit_textflow($tf, $x, $lowerY, $upperX, $y, '');
$pdf->delete_textflow($tf);


$pdf->end_page_ext('');
$pdf->end_document('');
return $pdf->get_buffer();
```

It is working, but as you can see, in optlist, I put `leftindent=0%`
and `leftindent=22%`

The problem is that if a key would be longer, I will have to increase the "leftindent" manually, otherwise it will not align with other pairs. Furthermore, what if the keys would be dynamic so I don't know their length? I wouldn't know how much "leftindent".

Is there a cleaner and better way to print name value paris using PDFLib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer your questions about the above answer in a new one. There you can format better.

Instead of `leftindent` you can also simply move your x position of the `fit_textflow()`. Hopefully that makes your code easier to understand.

About using **encoding=utf8**: I always get an error message then. Which PDFlib version are you using? (you can see in the phpinfo() output for example) Generally **utf8** is not a valid keyword unless you have crafted and provided an encoding yourself. But that would not be recommended.

From the PDFlib 10 API Reference, chapter 4.1, table 4.1:
[image]

About embedding: you must provide the font files in the SearchPath, because PDFlib needs the font data at runtime. Please refer to the *PDFlib 10 Tutorial, Chapter 3.1.4, and Chapter 6.3.4* "**Searching for Fonts**".  In the supplied PDFlib examples the SearchPath is set to "`../data`", where you can find the resources needed in the examples. You might want to crib there.

**Back to the table and accessibiltiy:**

In general it is already possible to create a table without a header, but this will be flagged in accessibility checks. Depending on how important the topic is, you should implement the table accordingly. On the other hand, your output is currently not accessible either, so you will have a much easier time if you put everything in a table. I have attached a very simple PDF/UA table which is created with the following code.
Maybe you can identify your problem more precisely.

[image: PDF/UA Table created with PDFlib 10]

```
<?php
/*
 *
 * Demonstrate automatic table tagging
 *
 * required software: PDFlib/PDFlib+PDI/PPS 10
 * required data: image file (dummy text created within the program)
 */

/* This is where the data files are. Adjust as necessary. */
$searchpath = dirname(__FILE__,3)."/input";
$title = "table_pdfua1";

$p = null;

try {
    $p = new pdflib();

    $tf = 0;
    $tbl = 0;
    $rowmax = 5;
    $colmax = 5;

    $llx = 50; $lly = 50; $urx = 550; $ury = 700;

    /* Dummy text for filling a cell with multi-line Textflow */
    $tf_text =
        "Sample text created with the Textflow feature in order to " .
        "create multiline content within a table cell.";

    /*
     * Set the search path for fonts and images etc.
     */
    $p->set_option(
        "errorpolicy=exception SearchPath={" . $searchpath . "}");
    

    if ($p->begin_document("", 
            "pdfua=PDF/UA-1 lang=en tag={tagname=Document}") == 0)
        throw new Exception("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());

    $p->set_info("Creator", "PDFlib Cookbook");
    $p->set_info("Title", $title);
    
    /* Automatically create spaces between chunks of text */
    $p->set_option("autospace=true charref");

    /* -------------------- Add table cells -------------------- */
    $row = 1;
    $col = 1;
   
    for ($row; $row <= $rowmax; $row++) {
    /* ----- Simple text cell */
    $col = 1;

    $optlist = "colwidth = 100 fittextline={fontname=NotoSerif-Bold fontsize=10 position={left top}} margin=5";

    $tbl = $p->add_table_cell($tbl, $col, $row, "text " . $row, $optlist);

    /* ----- Multi-line text with Textflow */
    $col++;

    $optlist = "fontname=NotoSerif-Regular fontsize=10";

    $tf = $p->add_textflow(0, $tf_text, $optlist);

    $optlist = "colwidth=300 rowheight=8 margin=5 textflow=" . $tf . " fittextflow={firstlinedist=capheight}";

    $tbl = $p->add_table_cell($tbl, $col, $row, "", $optlist);
    }

    /* ---------- Place the table on one or more pages ---------- */

    /*
     * Loop until all of the table is placed; create new pages as long
     * as more table instances need to be placed.
     */
    do {
        $p->begin_page_ext(0, 0, "width=a4.width height=a4.height");
        
        $p->create_bookmark("Tagged table demo", "");
        
        $p->fit_textline("Name-Value pairs", 50, 750,
            "fontname=NotoSerif-Regular " .
            "fontsize=16 tag={tagname=H1}");
        
        /*
         * Shade every other $row; draw lines for all table cells. Add
         * "showcells showborder" to visualize cell borders
         */
        $optlist = "tag={tagname=Table Summary={key value tablese}} ";
        /* Place the table instance */
        $result = $p->fit_table($tbl, $llx, $lly, $urx, $ury, $optlist);

        if ($result == "_error")
            throw new Exception("Couldn't place table : "
                    . $p->get_errmsg());

        $p->end_page_ext("");
    }
    while ($result == "_boxfull");

    /* Check the $result; "_stop" means all is ok. */
    if (!$result == "_stop") {
        if ($result == "_error") {
            throw new Exception("Error when placing table: " 
                                        . $p->get_errmsg());
        }
        else {
            /*
             * Any other return value is a user exit caused by the
             * "return" option; this requires dedicated code to deal
             * with.
             */
            throw new Exception("User return found in Textflow");
        }
    }

    /* This will also delete Textflow handles used in the table */
    $p->delete_table($tbl, "");

    $p->end_document("");
    $buf = $p->get_buffer();
    $len = strlen($buf);

    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Length: $len");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" . $title . ".pdf");
    print $buf;
}
catch (PDFlibException $e) {
    echo("PDFlib exception occurred in" . $title . "sample:\n" .
        "[" . $e->get_errnum() . "] " . $e->get_apiname() . ": " .
        $e->get_errmsg() . "\n");
    exit(1);
}
catch (Throwable $e) {
    echo($e);
    exit(1);
}

$p = 0;
?>
```

this sample is adapted from the PDFlib Cookbook "[pdfua/table_pdfua1](https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/pdfua/table_pdfua1/php/)".

However, I suspect that the accessibility issue is not a real problem for you, so you could simply implement the whole thing with a PDFlib table. Just ask the person what the table and accessibility concerns are. Because if the real Tagged PDF (PDF/UA) is not an issue, many things become easier.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to make it with a table as you said, on Edge the screen reader reads it correctly. The problem is on the software that they are using for screen reader that for read it badly on Adoble Acrobat (it says that it is a table, and If i put too much space between columns, it reads firsty the entire column 1 then the entire column 2 instead of read with the right order). So sadly I can not use the table as solution, but I will find a way to make the PDF working with just their screen with textflow. (continue in the next comment because this is too long)

Comment: I still considerer this the right answer because, as you said, the table is accessible. They are using a screen reader that reads it badly and says that it is a table. About the utf8, I will use `unicode` as you said, because if I put the "embedding" option it will give error with utf8. Just a last questione: Why in the official documentation they don't use load_font but they repeat the font every time? I mean, in this way `$font = $pdf->load_font('NotoSerif', 'unicode', '');` then `$optlist = "font=" . $font . " fontsize=10";` they would avoid to repeat the fontname. Is load_font bad?

Comment: PDFlib can load a font implicit and explicit and the result is identical. In PDFlib 10 Tutorial chapter 6.3.1 I found the following: _"Fonts can be loaded explicitly with the PDF_load_font( ) method or implicitly by supplying the fontname and encoding options to methods such as PDF_add/create_textflow( ) or PDF_fill_textblock( )."_ Personally, I find using the font name in the examples provided much clearer than using the font handle. But that is certainly a matter of taste. The font is not loaded again if it has already been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

> I know the easiest solution would be to use a table, but I can't because the PDF has to be accessible and they told me that

who said that? This statement is a bit too general for now. Also, your content is not accessible in any way, because you achieve this in the PDF only through Tagged PDF.

PDFlib can be used to create PDF/UA (i.e. Tagged PDF) which can be used to create accessible PDFs.

The easiest way would be to follow the PDFlib 10 Coobkook example https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/pdfua/table_pdfua1/php/ and fill one table cell after the other with a textflow.

Then PDFlib 10 will generate the table tagging for you, and you will have a nice accessible PDF. (See also PDFlib 10 Tutorial, Chapter 11.2.1 "Automatic Table Tagging"). The tutorial is included in the PDFlib 10 package, as well available on the [download page](https://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-product-family/).

For PDF/UA please also refer to Chapter 11.4.1 "The PDF/UA-1 Standard" in the PDFlib 10 Tutorial. Your code fragment already shows that you must at least change the font, because the font must be embedded. In your case you are using the PDF Latin Core font Helvetica which is not embedded. Therefore I recommend to use a font that you have and like. As an example you could of course use the NotoSerif-Regular used in the PDFlib examples.

if you want to stick with your solution, you could first determine the length for each key entry. You can do this via `info_textline()` with the same font options as when placing the text with `fit_textline()`. You could use this to determine the maximum length and then adjust the llx position for the textflows accordingly.
I would not use leftindent, but pass different X values for fit_textline() and fit_texfflow().

Also, I would get the end position with `info_textflow()`, not with `get_option("texty")`.

I think you are always better off with a PDFlib table. And if you really want to create Tagged PDF, that is also possible with PDFlib 10.

One comment about your used options:

```
$label_optlist = "fontname={Helvetica} fontsize=7 encoding=utf8 fakebold=true leftindent=0%";
```

`encoding=utf8` is not valid. The correct option value is "**encoding=unicode**". You can set `$pdf->set_optin("stringformat=utf8");` when your input content is UTF-8. In PDFlib 10 `stringformat=utf8` and `encoding=unicode` is default and can be omitted.

Comment: firstly, thank you for the reply. Is a table without header and with in columns 1 the names, and in columns 2 the values, accessible?
The reason I'm using leftindent, is to inline all the values. I mean, look the sceenshot in the post, without leftindent, they would not be inline as they are with leftindent

Comment: about the encoding, what would be the difference if I use `$pdf->set_option("stringformat=utf8");` and put `encoding=unicode` or if I do not use the set_option and put `encoding=utf8`? Currently with only `encoding=utf8` it seems to works

Comment: About the "embedding", what does it do? I tried to put `embedding` but i got this error `Font 'Helvetica' with encoding 'utf8': Font cannot be embedded`. I tried to change encoding to `unicode` as you said and it works. But what is the difference between `fontname={Helvetica} fontsize=8 embedding encoding=unicode` and `fontname={Helvetica} fontsize=8 encoding=utf8`? Sorry for noob questions and sorry if I split them in 3 comments, but SO says too many characters xD